# SQLAlchemy + MySQL connections blocking for several hours

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy 0.9.1 + MySQL 5.6.19a (via Amazon RDS), and it's been working well under heavy load (dozens of processes reading & writing simultaneously) for several months. This morning I see that several processes were blocked for several hours when trying to read and/or write to the database.

I'm using a session_scope as suggested in the SQLAlchemy docs:

```
@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of SQLAlchemy operations."""

    session = SESSION()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

so for example:

```
with session_scope() as session:
    # Create a new record, set timestamp
    record = MetricsSnapshot()
    record.timestamp = timestamp
    session.add(record)
```

and I see that the my code never raised an exception. It just seems to have blocked for about four hours, and then continued. I don't think has happened in the past, but I'm not sure what could have caused it.

Is it conceivable that timeouts in SQLAlchemy or MySQL are set high enough to allow a four hour delay? Is there anything else I might be able to check to figure out what happened?

Comment: Your timeout question: if you haven't done anything in particular in SQLAlchemy to define queues, timeout will be defined to a "reasonable value", probably half a minute, see [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#connection-pool-configuration). As for MySQL, honestly I don't know. And as for your problem, you don't have logs or any other kind of clue?

Comment: @Irnzcig I do have quite a few logs, but they just show my code blocking for about 4 hours, and then continuing to execute (if an exception had been raised, I would see that in the logs and I don't see any). So it's pretty tricky to tell what happened! I can't imagine any timeouts default that high.

Comment: but then why do you suspect that the problem was caused by the ddbb? Your process could have been blocked by other reasons (not that I have many ideas about what these other could be). Even if you don't have exceptions in your log, do you see any operation starting and then getting stalled for 4 hours? You see no operations at all for 4 hours?

Comment: I see what you're asking - sorry for the confusion! I do see log messages immediately before and immediately after the above "so for example" block of code. So I'm pretty sure my process is blocked for 4 hours somewhere within that code (and then after 4 hours it continues executing without problems).

Comment: No problem! So you are just getting a new session and adding a new register... Weird! Anyway, it may be that there is an explanation not assuming that the ddbb is the deadlock. It could be that the python process gets stalled when creating the new record for example. Does it make any sense to you? (Not much to me, honestly.) Could be concurrency for any resource of the machine? You say it is heavy load.... I guess you don't have a log on the status on the machine itself... Sorry I cannot be of much help.

Comment: Yep any of those things are definitely possible. I think I'll just have to add more logging and try to figure out how to get it to happen again.